# Emacs open /path/to/filename:xx:yy

Tags: emacs, filenames

I have following needs on opening file with Emacs:

1. emacs /path/to/file  ;; default
2. emacs /path/to/file  ;; if path doesn't exists, create it,then create the file
3. emacs /path/to/file:15 ;; open file and goto line 15
4. emacs /path/to/file:15:16   ;; open file and goto line 15 column 16
5. emacs /path/to.file:15:16:  ;; open file and goto line 15 column 16

If you have the same functionalities implemented in your dotfile, It will be greatly appreciated if you could share it here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In elisp you can use a function like this, that you can put in your `init.el`:

```
(let ((file-to-open (split-string (second command-line-args) ":")))
 (progn
   (find-file (first file-to-open))
   (if (>= (length file-to-open) 2)
     (progn (goto-char (point-min))
           (forward-line
            (- (string-to-int (second file-to-open)) 1))))
   (if (= (length file-to-open) 3)
    (forward-char
     (- (string-to-int (third file-to-open)) 1)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a bash function parsing the line and col parameters?

```
function myemacs { if echo $1 | grep -q ":" ; then COL=$(echo $1 | cut -d: -f3); emacs $(echo $1 | cut -d: -f1) +$(echo $1 | cut -d: -f2):${COL:-0}; else emacs $1; fi }
```

Comment: Thanks @eMMe ! I wonder if there's a more portable solution. A recipe that I could put into my emacs config file.